# What connotation does "unhealthy relationships" have?

Tags: phrases

What connotation does "unhealthy relationships" have? I'm told that it can't be used to mean strained or stormy relations with someone. Why?

Answer (score 1):

"Healthy" and "unhealthy" are judgments, based on individual or cultural beliefs about how the world works.

Unhealthy relationships are dysfunctional in some way - a win/lose or lose/lose for those involved. "Strained" and "stormy" are not necessarily indicators of unhealthy relationships; they could show that difficult conversations are being had rather than suppressed.

Some signs that I would associate with unhealthy relationships: resentment, passive-aggressive behavior, aggression, depression, controlling.

Answer (score 0):

An "unhealthy relationship" is usually used to indicate a relationship in which the parties are not allowed or enabled to play the role they are supposed to play within that relationship.

What those supposed roles are is often culturally defined; what can be seen as a "healthy relationship" in one culture can be seen as "unhealthy" in another.

If we take *friendship* as an example relationship, it is often assumed that in a "good" friendship, both friends give an take. They both invest time and energy to give something worthwhile to the other. 
In some cases however, it can seem that one party only profits from the "friendship", while the other only invests. That would often be called an _unhealthy relationship.

As for *strained* or *stormy* relationships, this is *usually* used to mean a relationship that is experiencing problems, but not necessarily because of the "unhealthy" nature of the relationship. An *unhealthy* relationship **can** become a strained relationship when the "giving" party realizes that they are being short-changed. If the parties in the relationship then have fights over that, the relationship can become stormy.

The essential difference is that in case of an unhealthy relationship, the relation between the parties does not conform to the (social, cultural) expectations of such a relationship. A strained or stormy relationship refers usually to the specific behaviour of the people in a relationship, without the connotation that actual social or cultural taboos have to have been broken.

Let me try to give an example (which by force is culturally coloured!)

In many Western countries, a marriage is thought of as a relationship between two individuals with equal rights, entered into out of free will by both participants, based on a romantic notion of love.

Hence, from that background, a forced or arranged marriage may (and often is) deemed "an unhealthy relationship". Similarly, if one of the spouses mentally or physically abuses the other, while the other accepts that treatment, it stands to be called "unhealthy".

Now a marriage between two consenting adults that dearly love each other will in this situation be seen as healthy, but it can become strained, for instance when the relationship suffers due to, say, financial problems. It will not be called "unhealthy".

Because of the strain of financial problems, the two spouses may end up fighting a lot. The relationship can be said to be "stormy", but not necessarily "unhealthy".

Comment: sorry that was strained or stormy. I'll correct